# Is there a multi-class classification model which can incorporate partly known conditional probabilities of the targets?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, conditional-probability, multi-class

I am faced with a classification problem where I wish to predict 2 binary variables, say x and y. x and y are dependent in the sense that one conditional probability vanishes: P(y=1 | x=0) = 0. I am looking for a model that is able to incorporate this assumption, which is, of course, reflected in my data.

As of now, there are two approaches I can think of:

1. Fit 1 model that predicts P(x) on the entire training data. Fit a second model that predicts P(y | x=1 ) by using only the subset of the training data where x=1. To obtain P(y) for the test data, simply multiply the outputs of the two models, i.e. P_hat(y=1) = P_hat(x=1) * P_hat(y=1 | x=1)
2. Fit a multi class classification model, modifying the loss function such that predictions of the form (x=0, y=1) increase the loss substantially

I lean towards the first approach as it seems simpler and more theoretically sound in my eyes. The caveat is that, the overall sample is different to the subsample of x=1 data points, and so it would be invalid to apply the second model to the overall data.

Are there any other methods that could treat this problem well? I should note that my data only has a few thousand rows and is somewhat imbalanced (10-20% have x=1, and then ~30% of x=1 data points have y=1)